# excel formula for the week according to the start date

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want to fill in the "week" column with excel formulas for the week according to the start date of the data. Please Solution.

For Week 1 starting from row 2 and counting every 7 rows.

Thanks

| DATE | WEEK |
| --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 03/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 04/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 06/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 07/12/2022 | Week 1 |
| 08/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 09/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 10/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 11/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 12/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 13/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 14/12/2022 | Week 2 |
| 15/12/2022 | Week 3 |

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @CetinBasoz , I want to fill in the week column according to the date of the data that started

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula like the one displayed. The English functions are ROUNDUP() and DAYS().
[image]

---

The following refers to a case in which you need calendar weeks instead:

Try to use the WEEKNUM() function, it returns the calendar week of a date. If you determine the week of the starting date, you can solve this via simple substraction for any later week. (KALENDERWOCHE() is the German version of this function)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the answer formula from you not yielding "week1" on "01-12-2022"

Comment: I added screenshots, now it should work for you.

Comment: Now you paste the text data I posted example date "04/12/2022" the result using the formula from you is week "2" but the result should still be week "1"

Comment: I thought you worked with calander dates, because the first week only exsists out of 6 days. So to be clear: From a date you want to start counting 7 day's. Each set of 7 days is a new week right?

Comment: @AndersBalari , Actually I want to calculate from the start date "01-12-2022" to the 07-12-2022" date then it means the first week because it amounts to 7 days

Comment: @Malf I realised it in parallel to you adding this comment. The answer already is adapted. I left the other one in, if someone needs calendar week diffs.

Comment: @AndersBalari , Thank you for the answer from you last appropriate but there is something I want to ask if `29-12-2022 30-12-2022 31-12-2022 ` dengan formula `="WEEK "&ROUNDUP((DAY(A2))/7,0)` Result `Week 5` should be Week 1

Comment: @Malf Please do have a look at my screenshot again. You have to use the DAYS function, not the DAY function. The DAYS formula takes two arguments, the second argument does have to be a fixed reference to the cell containing your start date.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to fill that column with WeekNum() values, right? Then:

```
Range('B2:B16').FormulaR1C1 = '=Weeknum(Offset(R[0]C[0],0,-1))'
```

EDIT: I think you mean that you want to enumerate starting row 2 and add text "Week" in front:

```
Range('B2:B16').FormulaR1C1 = '= "Week " & TEXT(CEILING.MATH( (ROW()-1)/7),"00")'
```

EDIT2: Excel 2010 version compatible (that you should have said from the start):

```
Range('B2:B16').Formula = '= "Week " & TEXT(CEILING( (ROW()-1)/7,1),"00")'
```

Comment: thank you for the reply from you but the result has not matched the result I want

Comment: The answer from you is the same as the formula answer

Comment: @Malf, What do you mean. To get an answer you should explain what you want. For example what result would you expect and why?

Comment: @Malf, which formula are you talking about? It is already a formula, yes.

Comment: Actually I want to calculate from the start date "01-12-2022" to the 07-12-2022" date then it means the first week because it amounts to 7 days

Comment: @Malf what you are saying is hardly understood. You were not talking about Weeknum() or IsoWeekNum() but just name with text like Week 1 starting from row 2 and counting every 7 rows. Check edit then.

Comment: I'm using excel 2010 so results like `#NAME?` using vba code from you

Comment: @Malf, try just CEILING() I am not here for you to check and test code for every version you might have and didn't tell from the start.

Comment: @Malf, edited to add 2010 compatible one :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that Anders Balari is right. Normally the answer of `=weeknum(A1)` is week 49. You want to substract (49-1) 48 weeks from it so you can 'start' week 1 on december 1st. If you want that, you should make a function with a code like:

```
Sub week()

    Dim intWeek As Integer
    Dim intCounter, intCounterNew As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    'assuming the dates are in column 1 starting in row 1
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      
    intLastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    intCounterNew = 1
    
    For intCounter = 1 To intLastRow
        
        intWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(wsData.Cells(intCounter, 1))
        
        If intCounter <> 1 Then
            If intWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(wsData.Cells(intCounter - 1, 1)) Then
                wsData.Cells(intCounter, 2) = "week " & intWeek - (intWeek - intCounterNew)
            Else
                intCounterNew = intCounterNew + 1
                wsData.Cells(intCounter, 2) = "week " & intWeek - (intWeek - intCounterNew)
            End If
        Else
            wsData.Cells(1, 2) = "week " & intWeek - (intWeek - intCounterNew)
        End If
        
    Next intCounter

End Sub
```

Be aware I made no function, but a macro that goes through the set of dates. I tried and it worked.

[image: Result]

I don't know how to create a function like that.

Comment: Actually I want to calculate from the start date "01-12-2022" to the 07-12-2022" date then it means the first week because it amounts to 7 days

Answer (score 0):

Allright: I think I figured it out. This code:

```
Sub CustomWeeks()
'assuming the dates are in column 1 starting in row 1

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim intCounter, intLastRow, intWeeknumber, intDayCounter As Integer

Set wsData = ActiveSheet
intLastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

intWeeknumber = 1
intDayCounter = 1

For intCounter = 1 To intLastRow

    If intCounter = 1 Then
        wsData.Cells(intCounter, 2) = "Week " & intWeeknumber
        intDayCounter = intDayCounter + 1
    Else
        If intDayCounter > 7 Then
            intDayCounter = 1
            intWeeknumber = intWeeknumber + 1
            wsData.Cells(intCounter, 2) = "Week " & intWeeknumber
            intDayCounter = intDayCounter + 1
        Else
            wsData.Cells(intCounter, 2) = "Week " & intWeeknumber
            intDayCounter = intDayCounter + 1
        End If
    End If
Next intCounter
    
End Sub
```

Results in what you mean. So: On day one, week one will start and will be week 1 for 7 days. After that you go to week 2 and so on. Is this what you mean?

[image: Result]